# How do you get a compiled image for an older version of postsharp?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, postsharp

I pulled code down from my work repo. It works on other devs machines. They are using postsharp 4.0.42 and when I install it, it doesnt prompt me to install a compiled image. I either need better support for upgrading our project (we followed the directions to update post-sharp but there are a ton of errors), or a way to install a compiled image of this older version.

I have uninstalled and re-installed VS 2019 and it worked for a little bit without me installing an image but now its not working again.

The actual error: "The PostSharp Tools for Visual Studio is not installed, is disabled, or must be updated."
- It is installed though. I can see it under extensions and it is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

After you build a project that uses PostSharp 4.0.42, go to folder `C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\4.0.42\bin.Release` which PostSharp creates on your computer. Inside, run the file `PostSharp.HQ.v3.0.exe` and check "Ask to install compiled images during compilation" under "Speed Up the Builds".

Then, kill the process `postsharp.srv.4.0-x86.exe` if it's running and rebuild your project with PostSharp.

You should then receive a prompt to install the compiled images. This way, you can have precompiled images even if you don't have the PostSharp Tools for Visual Studio extension.

Errors you face upgrading from 4.0 to the current version (6.3) are probably for another question or for support.